# CoffeeScript debugging process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, coffeescript, runtime-error

I'm new to the CoffeeScript and Rails generally, and every time I get an `ExecJS::RuntimeError` I have to manually go through each of the CoffeeScript files I've been working to find out what's wrong, since the Rails informs me that I've got, for instance, an `unmatched OUTDENT` and it's somewhere around line six, which is `*/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, where all of my javascript is compiled. The problem is that the files keep grow in size and quantity and my debugging process becomes nightmarish. What can I do to find out in what exact `*.coffee.js` file an error has occurred?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coffeescript compilation error in ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955528/coffeescript-compilation-error-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

In rails 4.2 when I make syntax error in any file I get more descriptive error message. I can't check it at the moment but as I remember in Rails 3 I had the same issue as you have. Solution? Change small number of files at once and run browser/specs.

Answer (score 0):

(Copying [my answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41700235/1836506))

One workaround is to compile your `.coffee` files outside rails to get a decent error message:

If you don't yet have it:

```
npm i coffee-script -g
```

Then in a parent directory of your .coffee files:

```
coffee --output deleteme --compile .
```

When you're done, delete the `deleteme` folder it created (which is only created if you fix all the errors). This should find the syntax error for you and tell you exactly where it is.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplica‌​te-answer-to-several-questions)

Comment: Got it. Flagged. (Or rather, flag suggested.)

Comment: Next step, delete this : )