# Coffeescript compilation error in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, pre-compilation

I am using coffeescript+ruby-on-rails. The compilation of coffeescript into pure JS leads to an error if there is a syntax problem in the coffee code. On the browser when I run the app, I get this error: [ExecJS::RuntimeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362458/error-when-running-rails-app-execjsruntimeerror/31733290#31733290)

Is there any way to find out what caused the compilation error, when it was trying to compile coffee code to JS?
Attached is a screenshot of the error[image]

Following is the entry in the server log, which no way indicates the file which actually caused the syntax error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: [stdin]:25:10: unexpected :):
    4:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    5:     <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Inmonarch Website" %></title>
    6:     <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Inmonarch Website" %>">
    7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    9:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   10:   </head>
  app/views/layouts/dashboard.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_dashboard_html_erb__3120053487817944018_56303120'


  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (7.4ms)
  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (25.5ms)
  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (296.8ms)
  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/vipin8169/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails426/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (313.8ms)
```

PS:- I know what the syntax error is, I made the syntax error deliberately to find out if I am able to trace the error with the help of logs, which I couldn't.

Comment: Here is a low-quality answer: from your data I feel that "SyntaxError: [stdin]:25:10: unexpected :" is interesting - you could dig to find that stdin and try to look around line 25, symbol 10 and something could be wrong with ':' symbol. You also have options to see 'Application Trace' 'Framework Trace' or 'Full Trace' - generaly those things have interesting info too.

Comment: Here is another low-quality method: you could reduce your coffeeScript step-by-step, throwing away feature-by-feature of your script until you get no compilation errors. This could indicate a place where things went wrong. You could use external syntax-checker tool to test your coffeeScript code as it seems that you have a syntax error.

Comment: 'Application Trace' 'Framework Trace' or 'Full Trace'  doesn't have anything useful. 25:10 correctly says about the location of the error, but how do I get to know the file name in which the syntax error is present? What does [stdin] refer to?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I didn't include the code because it was not required. I know what the syntax error is, I made the syntax error deliberately to find out if I am able to trace the error with the help of logs, which I couldn't. Hence, I posted a question here.

Comment: Probably, I was not clear enough. Sorry.

Comment: Do you have `config.assets.debug = true` in `config/environments/development.rb`? This should be on by default, and should split out the files...

Comment: Yes, it is true in the development.rb

Comment: It *should* be `true`, which *should* split out the `application.js` in individual files as loaded with Sprockets (`#= require ...` lines).

Comment: Yes, It does split the files. I can see all the files individually in the sources tab of firebug. But, I am not sure about how does that help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One workaround is to compile your `.coffee` files outside rails to get a decent error message:

If you don't yet have it:

```
npm i coffee-script -g
```

Then in a parent directory of your `.coffee` files:

```
coffee --output deleteme --compile .
```

When you're done, delete the `deleteme` folder it created (which is only created if you fix all the errors). This should find the syntax error for you and tell you exactly where it is.

Answer (score -2):

You can use an online linter like http://www.coffeelint.org/ if you know its coffeescript causing the error

Comment: that might drive you crazy if you have a zillion coffee files and have no idea which one is in error!